# Listview with multiple clocks

Tags: java, android, listview, timer, runnable

I'm trying to create a listview that will hold multiple clocks but the time in each row is always jumping around.

in my getView I have

```
        Date date=new Date();
        chagre.setTag(position);
        Handler mClockHandler = new Handler();
        mUpdateClockTask clockTask = new mUpdateClockTask(chagre,
                chagre.getTag().toString(), date);
        mClockHandler.post(clockTask);
```

And runnable

```
public class mUpdateClockTask implements Runnable {
    private TextView tv;
    Handler mClockHandler = new Handler();
    String tag;
    Date date;

    public mUpdateClockTask(TextView tv,
            String tag, Date date) {
        this.tv = tv;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (tv.getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
            SimpleDateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a");
            String time = TIME_FORMAT.format(date);                 
            tv.setText(time.trim());
            mClockHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't create all the rows in a list at the same time - it creates them as you scroll to them and destroys them afterwards, or often it will recycle a row that appeared elsewhere in the list. Your Runnables have a reference to a `TextView` that is being used for random rows in the list and could be destroyed unexpectedly.

Comment: So what would be the best way to accomplish this from not happening?